# Working of Border radius for chrome for div tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have two circular concentric divs one on the other. I have to show alerts on the click of those two circles.

My HTML code looks like :

```
<div id="circle2" style="position: absolute.display:none;left:14px;top:35px;width:266px;height:266px;background-Color:#EFA927;border-radius:50% 50%;" onclick="alert('2');"></div>

<div id="circle1" style="position: absolute;display:none;left:31.5px;top:52.5px;width:231px;height:231px;background-Color:#0080C0;border-radius:50% 50%;" onclick="alert('1');"></div>
```

Everything works fine for Mozilla but for chrome at the left-top ,right-top , top-bottom , left-bottom corner of circle1 chrome is giving me alert for circle1 (circle 2 is expected).

Is there any way to rectify this thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't completely understand your question, but using this code there's no problem:

```
<div id="circle2" style="left:14px;top:35px;width:266px;height:266px;background-Color:#EFA927;border-radius:50% 50%;" onclick="alert('2');"></div>

<div id="circle1" style="left:31.5px;top:52.5px;width:231px;height:231px;background-Color:#0080C0;border-radius:50% 50%;" onclick="alert('1');"></div>
```

When you click on the `circle1`, it alerts "1", on `circle2` it alerts "2".

Comment: I think the problem is the fact that the circles overlap and click events are thrown from the bounding box (rectangle not circle). It works correctly if you click circle2 at the top where the boxes don't overlap but not in the (invisible) corners. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XRdFC/2/

Comment: I know it should work :( please open it in chrome and click on yellow circle at all possible locations

Comment: Now i see; as thomas said, the problem is that the div is a square even if you see it as a circle; making circles with border don't cut the part of the div that is rounded

Comment: that's right. I want the div to be seen circular on the chrome also. Is there any wat to do it?

Comment: As far as i know, you can't in Webkit browsers

Answer (score 1):

You might try using image maps:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/the-map-element.html#image-maps

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/map

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Img

Working sample [**here**](http://www.sanbarcomputing.com/flat/forumPosts/src/imageMap/imageMap.html)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="concentricCircles_304x304_284x284.png" usemap="#annularMap" alt="Circle within circle">
    <map name="annularMap">
        <area id="inner" shape=circle coords="152,152,142" alt="Red circle" onclick="alert(2);">
        <area id="outer" shape=circle coords="152,152,152" alt="Yellow border" onclick="alert(1);">
    </map>
</p></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no problem here.

Check this out. http://jsfiddle.net/XRdFC/

Oh well, I did change 'on-click' to 'onclick'. Might have made the difference.

Comment: If you add `div { position: absolute }` so the rendering matches the description in the question, that exhibits the problem described in the question.

Comment: Thanks... but my circles are concentric one above the other ... and i typed on-click to avoid spelling mistakes ..

Comment: Yeah, that's what I couldn't figure out, and got a vote-down :P
Anyways, I hope Quentin's resolution worked.